# Using the Rally API to change the rank of an item

Tags: ajax, rally

I am trying to use the Rally web service API to reorder 2 items.

From looking at the documentation i should be able to do:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/12345?rankAbove=/slm/webservice/v2.0/task/56789,
        type: 'PUT',
        headers: { Authorization: Basic mytoken },
        success: function(data) {

          //do something

        }
    });
```

but i'm getting an error:

```
Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected '{' but saw '' [ chars read = \u003E\u003E\u003E\u003C\u003C\u003C ]"
```

The documentation doesn't seem to reveal what I could be doing wrong.

Cheers for your help

Comment: What is myToken?  Is it an api key?

Comment: I've tried with an API token and with my username and password base64 encoded. The keys allow me to list items from the API so I know they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use basic auth to do this because there is an additional CSRF token you need to pass.  I think you can make it work with an api key though:

```
headers: { zsessionid: myToken }
```

You didn't have any issues with reading data because the CSRF protection only kicks in when attempting to modify data.

For what it's worth, the App SDK generally handles most of this complexity for you.  It looks like you're using jquery in your app here instead, which is why you need to do this low level stuff...

Comment: Thanks I'll try the token header for the JavaScript. I've been using the c# library but couldn't see anything that would do the ranking for me built in. Have you got an example of how to use the web app to do it?

Comment: As long as you're using the latest version of the .net toolkit you should be able to just use the overload of the Update method that takes a NameValueCollection of parameters (like rankAbove): http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/47057c17-e7c6-4386-18ae-907698df2891.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've changed direction and used the c# functionality in a handler instead of hand crafting some jQuery to do it instead. I've managed to get basic updates to the content done, however the rankAbove and rankBelow Doesn't seem to affect the ranking. I've copied the example from the documentation exactly, but can't get them to move. Have you got any hints for it?

Comment: I worked out what i was doing wrong, oh the joy of Rally. I wanted to reorder TASKS, but tasks do not use Rank, they use TASKINDEX. You have to manually set the taskIndex AND update all the indexs after it (it doesn't do it for you)

Comment: You should be able to do taskIndexAbove and taskIndexBelow parameters much like you would with rank...  I agree it's weird that task ranking is completely different...  Glad you got it working though.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks. Is there a list of all the parameters somewhere that can be used?

Comment: I couldn't find docs for the rank/taskIndex ones discussed here.  Most of the rest of them are in the WSAPI docs.  Also when in doubt you can usually just open up the dev tools in your browser when using Rally and see what those requests look like...